# Dynamically replace data based on matched RegEx JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, object

I have a dynamic template string, similar to the following:

```
There are {{num}} matches for the category {{category}}.
```

I also have an object like so:

```js
let data = {
  "num": // some value
  "category": // another value
}
```

How do I replace each template variable with the value presented in an object where the key is the text in the braces. For example:

```js
// example object
let data = {
  "num": "six",
  "category": "shoes"
}

// result
"There are six matches for the category shoes"
```

I have tried the following:

```js
messageRegEx = /{{(.*)}}/g
matchesMessage = template.replace(messageRegEx, data["$1"])
```

The code above replaces all instances of text in curly braces with `undefined`. I have looked at multiple StackOverflow questions, but none have addressed this issue.

Comment: `.replace(messageRegEx, (_,key)=>data[key])`

Comment: Oh, and use `(.*?)` in your regex, otherwise `key` will be `num}} matches for the category {{category`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, `replace()` allows to use a callback:

```js
matchesMessage = template.replace(
    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    (match, tag) => data[tag.trim()]
);

console.log(matchesMessage);
// "There are six matches for the category shoes."
```

Answer (score 1):

So just to be clear, you have an object with various properties, and you simply want to embed the values of those properties inside of a string?

One possible solution is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which allow you to embed data inside of a string. Basically, enclose your string inside of backticks instead of single or double quotes, and then surround expressions that represent your data with `${}`

Comment: To be clear, the string was dynamic (fetched by the client), so I couldn't have used a template literal. I didn't want to use a template language as the replacement was very easy.